# Compile, build and execute Qb64 code in Geany?

Tags: ide, geany, qb64

Good evening,

I installed Geany 1.24 in my computer and I have also installed QB64 (I don't remember which version and the official site is down). OS: Windows XP.

In Geany, when I write a program in Basic it doesn't compile it (aside from returning a succesfull compiled program). However, if I have an already compiled program it still doesn't compile it again (after making any change) but it lets me to execute it.

So I was wondering if anyone knows of a setup for the "Set Build Commands" to properly run QB64 in Geany. I also have Free Pascal IDE 2.6.4 installed and Geany recognized it on the first run and can compile and execute pascal code succesfully.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: this sounds more like a feature request. You should report that to Geany team directly.

Comment: I just thought Geany could compile/build QB64/FreeBasic already.

Answer (score 3):

Geany is only supporting FreeBasic in its latest 1.24 version out of the box -- not sure how similar these are.  You might get QB64 running by updating/changing file definitions. A good starting point would be [the manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#filetype-definition-files). If this not is working, you might like to patch Geany based on [the hacking guide](http://geany.org/manual/hacking.html#adding-a-filetype). There is a short checklist what to do to add a new file type from scratch.

If QB is quiet similar to FreeBasic, it might be enough to change `filettype_extensions.conf` to make your QB-scripts recognized as FreeBasic and update the build strings on menu Build- >configure build parameters (or something like that ... only got a German version here) -- it's the last point in the menu.

Comment: In 'filetype_extensions.conf' I already have: 'FreeBasic=*.bas;*.bi;' which is fine because I'm using .bas files. I'd only need to know how to configure the build parameters, I think I only need to set the "make" commands so I can make the .exe file.

Comment: Check how you can compile your documents via command line and adjust the build commands accordantly.

Comment: Ah sorry, but I have no idea how to compile from the command line.

Comment: Check this out or you will not be able to use Geany for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Geany to run QB64.EXE with the -x command line parameter:
QB -x yourfile.bas
In Geany, you need to go to the Tools menu, select Configuration files select Filetype configuration, Programming languages, filetypes.freebasic.
In filetypes.freebasic, change
fbc -w all "%f"
to
qb64 -x "%f"